# parallel-ssh not appears in any path after pip installation

Tags: bash, path, pip, parallel-ssh

we installed the  parallel-ssh

but after pip successfully installation the command parallel-ssh not appears in any path

where we are wrong?

```
 locate parallel-ssh
 which parallel-ssh
 /usr/bin/which: no parallel-ssh in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:
 parallel-ssh
 bash: parallel-ssh: command not found...
```

the pip installation

```
 pip install parallel-ssh
Collecting parallel-ssh
  Downloading 
.
.
.
Installing collected packages: asn1crypto, cryptography, pynacl, paramiko, greenlet, gevent, ssh2-python, parallel-ssh
  Found existing installation: cryptography 1.7.1
    Uninstalling cryptography-1.7.1:
      Successfully uninstalled cryptography-1.7.1
Successfully installed asn1crypto-0.24.0 cryptography-2.7 gevent-1.4.0 greenlet-0.4.15 parallel-ssh-1.9.1 paramiko-2.6.0 pynacl-1.3.0 ssh2-python-0.18.0.post1
```

Comment: Is that supposed to install a stand-alone executable? Isn't `pip` for installing python modules?

Comment: @terdon pip can install commands (e.g. awscli, ccm, etc.), but yes, parallel-ssh is just a plain old module.

Comment: The actual command to run might be `pssh`.  (You might be able to get a list of the files in the package with `pip show -f parallel-ssh`)